# Horizontally scrolling page navigation with 'forward' and 'back' buttons

Tags: javascript

I could use some help with rather basic javascript on a website layout I've just started if anyone can help.

Every page on my site is a section tag, all inline with eachother. I have a navbar at the top that successfully smooth scrolls horizontally to navigate to sections, but I'd like to have a right arrow button and left arrow button floating over the page content for advancing to the next or previous sections.

AI models can't seem to make this happen for me with JS. The code they provide only makes the right arrow button advance to my second section. Any help is much appreciated!

```
  <button id="scrollNext" class="scroll-button">▶</button>
<script>
    const scrollNextButton = document.getElementById('scrollNext');

    scrollNextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const currentSection = document.querySelector('section[data-active]');
        if (currentSection) {
            const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
            const currentIndex = [...sections].indexOf(currentSection);
            const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % sections.length;
            const nextSection = sections[nextIndex];

            nextSection.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: "start"
            });
        }
    });

    // Set new active on scroll
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const newActive = document.elementFromPoint(200, 200).getAttribute('id');

        sections.forEach(sec => {
            sec.removeAttribute('data-active');
        });

        document.querySelector('#' + newActive).setAttribute('data-active', true);

        // Update the button's href attribute based on the new active section
        scrollNextButton.setAttribute('href', `#${newActive}`);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a button that acts like a horizontal scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465691/how-can-i-create-a-button-that-acts-like-a-horizontal-scroll-bar)

Comment: You aren't updating the `data-active` attribute in your click handler, you are in your scroll handler but not the click handler. As far as the click handler is concerned it's always the same section that is data-active